Is there a voltage limit implemented in USB A to USB C charging?
We have a supplier that designed a battery pack for us. The pack has a USB C port, and comes with a USB A to USB C cable.
The cable only has two wires (V+ and GND), with CC resistors embedded in the USB C connector head. They state the pack can be charged up to 3A, but apparently will limit itself if it encounters a USB A source that cannot supply 3A. Looking at how this was implemented, I am skeptical about its robustness.
The charging circuit monitors the USB voltage coming onto the USB C port. The circuit determines limiting current by observing the voltage droop on the port. The design is hinged on the USB A source limiting its own current, and then dropping its own voltage to protect itself when its current limit is reached. The charging circuit stops increasing current when USB input voltage has dropped to ~4.25V, and regulates at that point.
I am much more versed in USB C PD type designs, and not in USB A to USB C systems. From what I have read, this is not the 'specified' way to do this. I have also read the USB A charging systems are a bit of the wild west. I have tested their implementation myself on several wall warts, and it appears to work, but I dont see how we can assume every USB A source will limit its own current in this way, or that every source should be operated in this manor.
Any thoughts or inputs on this would be appreciated.

I wrote an answer, but honestly, it's just worth a comment: This smells like a bad idea. There's definitely nothing that says that USB ports should "sag" a bit when their current limit is reached; quite the contrary, I'd actually expect them to be very stable up to a threshold, and then be off; that's proper design.

This is like the old USB chargers from the mid 2000s where you increase current until the voltage sags. My guess is someone took an iPod charger circuit and slapped a USB-C connector on it without updating anything else.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I have to assume the cable has plugs on both ends, Type-A and Type-C, and that the powerbank has a Type-C receptacle for charging.
The cable is not allowed to signal any other than "default" current and there are no data lines available, so the powerbank cannot know to what type of port the cable is plugged in.
It might be a standard USB port or BC charging port. Obviously, without any kind of negotiating it should not try to pull as much as current it can before voltage drops to 4.25V.
However, a DCP source should be fine with that - as long as the output voltage stays above 4.75V even at 500mA, up to 1.5A can be drawn and voltage is allowed to drop down to 2V.
Also a CDP source should be fine with that, the voltage stays always above 4.75V even at 1.5A.
Also many actual host USB ports may provide 1A or even more but they don't have to provide any more than 100mA without negotiation and 500mA when negotiated for USB2 ports, and up to 900mA when negotiated for USB3 ports.
Other proprietary charging standards may exist but it is unlikely the powerbank negotiates anything.
Many chargers actually drop the output voltage based on current, so that devices like phones can draw a lot of current and then less power needs to be dissipated in the phone - or at least they did when chargers were simple linear chips. But of course it allows for modern switch mode chargers to sense voltage drop so they don't draw too much current, which includes also voltage drop in the cable.
